# Configure ts-jest with multi-project jest setup

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I want to run jest tests across multiple sub projects. To do so I make use of [js-test](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/) but I seem to be missing some details about configuring it correctly.

[Here](https://github.com/maks-io/jest-with-multiple-projects-setup) you can find a very basic repo to reproduce my error. One can simply install it with `yarn` or `npm` and then run the only available script via `yarn test` (or `npm run test`) accordingly. The outcome is a set of two errors (one for each test in each sub-project), both complaining about the syntax of a referenced `.ts` file.

Is this fixable at all at the moment? I am aware of [this pinned issue](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/1648) but I cannot say for sure if this is 100% related.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!